# Where to add door for basement office at bottom of stairs with space constraints?

Tags: doors, framing, door-frame, basement-refinishing

I'm working on refinishing my basement and I want to turn one of the downstairs rooms into an office. I need to add a door to close off the room which happens to be entered from the bottom of the basement stairs. The problem is I don't have enough room at the bottom of the stairs to fit a standard width door, I only have about 26" from the last stair. Here's what I've thought of so far:

- Build the door back into the room a bit
- Angle the door
- Install a pocket door that runs along the stairs (downside here is the width would only be like 26" which is less than the 30" code in my state (MA).

I've attached a diagram showing what I'm considering and some pictures of the space. I'm open to other ideas if anyone has one! Thank you!

[image: Option 1]

[image: Option 2]

[image: Room View 1]

[image: Room View 2]

Comment: can you get by with an accordion pull-out door like used for utility closets?